# log file to JSON format

Tags: python, json

I have received a log file that needs to be parsed. It's in JSON but it's a log:

```
{
  "device_uuid": "abc",
  "os_ver": "9.3.1",
  "device_new": true,
  "carrier": "Comcast Cable",
  "model": "iPad Air",
  "customer_ids": {
    "customer_id": "abc123"
  }
}
{
  "device_uuid": "cde",
  "os_ver": "10.2",
  "device_new": true,
  "carrier": "Frontier Communications",
  "model": "iPhone 7",
  "customer_ids": {
    "customer_id": "cde123"
  }
}
{
  "device_uuid": "fgh",
  "os_ver": "10.2",
  "device_new": true,
  "carrier": "ATT",
  "model": "iPhone 6",
  "customer_ids": {
    "customer_id": "fgh123"
  }
}
```

My goal is to parse above log file into a pandas dataframe. Any suggestions?

Comment: If you google tinniest bit, you find your answer

Comment: Each line can be decoded with `json.loads`.

Answer (score 0):

Given the below sample data, this import to a `DataFrame` can be done with:

```
log_lines = pd.concat([pd.read_json(line) for line in my_json_lines])
```

Note: There are [plenty of other ways](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_json.html) to do this import.

```
my_json_lines = (
    '{"device_uuid":"abc", "os_ver":"9.3.1", "device_new":true,'
    '"carrier":"Comcast Cable","model":"iPad Air",'
    '"customer_ids":{"customer_id":"abc123"}}',
    '{"device_uuid":"cde","os_ver":"10.2","device_new":true,'
    '"carrier":"Frontier Communications","model":"iPhone 7",'
    '"customer_ids":{"customer_id":"cde123"}}',
    '{"device_uuid":"fgh","os_ver":"10.2","device_new":true,'
    '"carrier":"ATT","model":"iPhone 6",'
    '"customer_ids":{"customer_id":"fgh123"}}'
)
```